# Data tag parsing failed: Missing termination quote

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried to give myself a player head using this command:

```
/give @p skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:{Id:"ce27d2ce-ad02-4dfa-b3ee-bca732b2fd82",Properties:{textures:[{Value:"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly90ZXh0dXJlcy5taW5lY3JhZnQubmV0L3RleHR1cmUvNDQ0Y2Q1ZDJmZDJmZTM5N2RkYjkyN2UxODRmMTllY2JkMGZlMjRhZjZlZjY4ODUyYzE3MmFlNDQ3Y2Q0In19fQ=="}]}}}
```

But it didn't work, giving me this error:

```
Data tag parsing failed: Missing termination quote at: ...Q1ZDJmZDJmZTM5N2RkYjkyN2UxODRmMTllY<--[HERE]
```

This was the third time that this happened, when I tried to give myself a head (every time another) and the same error came up. How can I fix this?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Here's something that can help you out! [Why does pasting a command into the chat return an error?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371891/why-does-pasting-a-command-into-the-chat-return-an-error)

Comment: @Quijibo I am using 1.12.2. Kinda old, but it's still good after all.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 Thanks, gotta check it out.